# How to split the time between two dates over daily columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in much need of help please.

I have the table below.
It has about 300 rows and columns on the right for each day of the year starting 2015, ending 2019.  I only entered a few columns here as an example.

**What I need:**
A formula to split the time (it can be hours or decimal days, it doesn't matter) between the two days on the left on the columns to the right.
In the rest of the days, which are not included in the period, I need a zero in those columns.
I manually entered the results I need so it can help you understand.

**E.g.**
On the first row:
The employee has spent

- 15 hours at destination in the first day of travel,
- 24 hours in the second day of travel
- 11:50 hours in the last day of travel.

All the rest of the columns to the right, which are not here, starting *1/4/2015 23:59* should give the result zero.

Thank You!!

```
Entry Date  Exit Date   1/1/2015 23:59  1/2/2015 23:59  1/3/2015 23:59

1/1/15 9:00 1/3/15 11:50        15.00           24.00           11.50
```

Comment: please rewrite your data more clearly, if possible in a tabular format. What is the EXACT input, what is the exact desired output. If required, add a screenshot please.

Comment: When you say "it can be hours or decimal days, it doesn't matter" does that mean that it could be entered in either way & formula should deal with it, or do you mean we can decide which way the times should be entered?  It'll make a big difference to the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your help with editing. On the second line, the numbers 15, 24 and 11.50 are hours and they are the results I should get with the formula. I manually entered them to help you understand what I need. And yes, I mean you can decide which way the formula result should be expressed: hours or days.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it boils down to this

```
                   1.0 days       2.0 days       3.0 days       4.0 days

period=p in h/d.d  p-(1-(so far)) p-(2-(so far)) p-(3-(so far)) 0
```

**EDIT 2**: I've come up with a formula.

*NOTE*:
This formula assumes existence of a column that specifies 0 hours of work between the "end date/time" column ("B") and first work hour ("D"), so you have it like this:

```
    A               B               C       D               E               F               G               H
1   Entry Date      Exit Date       ZERO    1/1/2015 23:59  1/2/2015 23:59  1/3/2015 23:59  1/4/2015 23:59  1/5/2015 23:59
2   1/1/15 9:00     1/3/2015 11:50      0   0.6243055556    1               0.49375         0               0.00
3
```

The extra column is there to avoid circular dependencies, since
we must "iteratively" accumulate the hours

The main formula for row 2 from column D being:

```
=MIN(D1-$A2,MIN(MAX(($B2-$A2) - SUM($C2:C2), 0),1))
```

Note: semicolons may be needed instead of commas in Excel as delimiters.

Note: the last digit in the formula depends on the unit. Here it is in days decimal. If hours, put 24.

In plain English, for a cell

- Calculate sum of hours/days decimal in the range C to wherever - 1
- Subtract result from the difference between start and end (total hours)
- If less than 0, put 0 `(MAX(x, 0))`
- If more than 1, put 1 `(MIN(x, 1))`
- Choose between the result, or the difference between current date and start time, if it is smaller

Comment: Hi Agnes. Thank you so much! The result is exactly what I need!!! The problem is I really do not understand the formula. Sorry. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Will add in short time.

Comment: No hurry at all, whenever you can. Thank you!

Comment: This works just perfect. I need to add the condition to show zero for the rest of the columns, where the days do not fall between the start and end date. I tried to do this with the formula : =IF(C$1=MEDIAN($A$2,$B$2,C$1),(your formula),0). the thing is it does not work right for the last day of the period. Any idea on that?

Comment: Hi Agnes. This is PERFECT. thank you a million times. Really, for just taking so much time to help me, I can not describe how much it means to me. Wish I could give you a huge hug. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ela that's what this site is all about. I'm not a pro, and there might be different solutions, and I haven't time to check all the possible scenarios, so no hugs needed. I'm using Excel lately a lot, so I'm in the loop, but I do lack mathetmatical knowledge, so it took me more than actually was needed, still glad I could help.

Comment: I noticed a problem: if the D1 is a date higher than the interval, the formula shows 1. Also, if D1 is a date earlier then the interval, the formula gives a value with minus until D1 meets the start date and the formula works correctly. How could I get a zero for these cases as well? In the end I need to sum all those travel days and this false "1" values and all the minus values affect the final result.

Comment: Sorry for the buggy formula, lemme check how to modify it, I'll get back to you by 6 pm UTC (3 hrs from when this comment was posted)